# Getting an instance of an object from a Field, Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to modify some content that is located in a place where I have to use reflection to get to. The thing is that I want to get that values (which happens to be a list) as a Field and then change it. When I get the field do I get a reference (copy) of the Field or do I get the actual field (meaning if I edit it It will change from wherever I took it from) ?

```
  //Get command map
    Field field = this.getServer().getClass().getDeclaredField("commandMap");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    CommandMap cmdmap = (CommandMap) field.get(this.getServer());
    //Get commands map
    Field f = cmdmap.getClass().getDeclaredField("knownCommands");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Command> kcmds = (Map<String, Command>) f.get(cmdmap);
    //Unregister all
    for(String s: cmdToUnregister)
    {
        for(String fp : kcmds.keySet())
        {
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(kcmds.get(fp).getName()))
            {
                kcmds.remove(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    //Re set fields
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DivinityRealm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I tried this, it didn't work obiously. Whoever I don't know if the problem is my way of using Reflection or the fact that I am using a wrong approach?

Comment: Well you get a copy of the value in the field - but if that's a reference type, what's in the field *is* a reference. It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried - and if you haven't tried anything yet, please do so :)

Comment: What is the error? Anyway you modify `kcmds` structure while iterating on it, which could be a problem... Can you use Java 8?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis The error is that when the program gets the array back in another execution, said array contains the items I deleted. I am using Java 8

Comment: Please post the error trace. Which is the interested array? Is your application running on multiple threads? I'm asking because I can't find anything wrong in your use of reflection (the initial part), I think the problem is after you retreive the fields

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved when I figured that `kcmds` is actually a copy of the actual list and must be re set using reflection for it to actually make any change. Else you are just getting the copy and editing it for it to be GC'd